# Execute command troubles

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

`execute @e[type=armor_stand,name:"Luis Fonsi"] ~ ~ ~ /particle witchMagic ~ ~ ~ 0 0 0 1 1`

I'm trying to make a meme armor stand and add particle effects but I can't seem to get the execute command working because it doesn't see the name properly cause it has 2 words. I know I'm doing something wrong but no idea what

I'm playing in 1.12 on a server. If that helps
Entity '@e[type=armor_stand,name:"Luis' cannot be found
Error Message ^

Comment: Which version are you using? since 1.13, the command format has drastically changed and your format looks very much like before 1.13. and what error did you get?

Comment: Entity '@e[type=armor_stand,name:"Luis' cannot be found 
Is the error message and im playing on 1.12

Comment: It looks like the `name` selector argument doesn't support spaces in 1.12 (but does in 1.13 according to the wiki). A `score_is_luis_fonsi` selector argument might work as a workaround though.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to accomplish the same thing just by using this command:

```
execute @e[type=armor_stand,c=1] ~ ~ ~ /particle witchMagic ~ ~2 ~ 0 0 0 0 50
```

*Basically it looks for the closest armor stand which is the one i want to edit.
Its not really helpful if you want to do it by name but its an easy solution.*

:)

Comment: In the future: Use [tags](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Scoreboard#Tags_commands).

Comment: Archive link for my last comment: https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/index.php?title=Scoreboard&oldid=1260975#Tags_commands

Answer (score 0):

I think you should replace the name: with name=
So your command becomes:

```
execute @e[type=armor_stand,name="Luis Fonsi"] ~ ~ ~ /particle witchMagic ~ ~ ~ 0 0 0 1 1
```

I am not completely sure of this but I think it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You should change to the command below if you don't make this armorstand's name is visble

```
execute @e[type=armor_stand,name=Luis_Fonsi] ~ ~ ~ /particle witchMagic ~ ~ ~ 0 0 0 1 1
```